# Objective-C: Improve function

Tags: objective-c

I´m new to developing apps and I would like to have some hints about the code I have here:

```
- (IBAction)button_increase_click:(id)sender {
    int number = [self.label_content.text intValue];
    number+=1;
    NSString *increased_value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number];

    int count = [increased_value length];
    while (count<4) {
        increased_value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"0",increased_value];
        count = [increased_value length];
    }

    self.label_content.text = increased_value;  
 }
```

What I need to do is to increase the value of "label_content" by 1 and fill it with leading zeros until it has reached 4 digits. eg "0001" "0013" "0132".

So how can I improve the above code and take care of its readability?

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: You should be using binding and a number formatter for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method can look like this:

```
- (IBAction)button_increase_click:(id)sender {
    int number = [self.label_content.text intValue];
    number++;
    self.label_content.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d", number];
}
```

***Update*** For increasing readability use camel case for ivar method and other names. It's standard for iOS.

```
- (IBAction)increaseValue:(id)sender {
    int number = [self.contentLabel.text intValue];
    number++;
    self.contentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d", number];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See Apple's [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) Documentation.

A better number formatter:

```
int number = 4;
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d",number];
NSLog(@"number: %04d", number);
```

NSLog output:

> number: 0004